# Power automate "Link to Item" launches form in Classic, rather than Modern view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, power-automate, list-form

I have a SP Online list, which uses the default SP form (modern experience).  Once submitted, I have a Power Automate flow that sends an email containing a Link to Item link.  The problem is that this Link when clicked launches the submitted data in a Classic SharePoint form, rather than the Modern form.  If I double click the item in the list, it opens the Modern form correctly.  How can I get the Link to Item to launch the modern form, rather than the classic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I actually resolved this issue. Audience Targeting function was selected for classic mode. I unchecked, and now the form launches correctly.